# Preimage security of combined hash functions

Tags: hash, preimage-resistance

I am struggling with a property of combined hash function and more precisely concatenation.
I have seen that concatenating two collision resistant hash functions preserves this property (same for 2nd preimage resistance). But not always for the first preimage. Indeed, some explains that if the two concatenated hash functions are dependent, the result function could be first preimage weak even if the concatenated functions are preimage resistant. I don't see how it could happen.

First image resistance:
From y=H(x), it is computationally infeasible to find any input which hashes to that output y.

Comment: See [Generic Attacks on Hash Combiners](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/755)

Comment: @kelalaka If I'm not wrong, this is about collision and second preimage attack but not first preimage attack

Comment: It mentions inside, As far as I remember. Could you provide links for `some explains`..

Comment: this is what I've understood from slide 38 https://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~preneel/preneel_hash_tools_2012v1.pdf

Comment: and if we want to concatenate two first preimage resistant hash functions, the concatenation of the two needs to use depency between the two concatenated functions (if there is) otherwise it will be not computationally feasibe no?

Comment: *attacking the concatenation of the two will need to use the dependency between the two concatenated ones.  Maybe there is no need to have a depency between Ha and Hb such that H=Ha||Hb  will be 1st preimage weak if Ha,Hb 1st preimage resistant but that was an idea to find a counter exemple where the concatenation is not always preserving 1st preimage resistance.